# AS3 call a just added element

Tags: actionscript-3, call

i'm adding a movieclip element ("lastSlide") to an other movieclip element("endLogoButton"). The added element has a child which is a button("endLogoButton"). How can i call that button?

```
    mcSlideHolder.addChild(lastSlide);
  /*mcSlideHolder.getChildByName("endLogoButton").buttonMode = true;;
    mcSlideHolder.getChildByName("endLogoButton").mouseChildren = false;
    mcSlideHolder.getChildByName("endLogoButton").useHandCursor  = true;*/
    lastSlide.endLogoButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, linkClick);
```

As a beginner i'm struggling around ... but can't make it work ...
It always tells me that the access to a Nullobject reference is not possible.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you having this issue when the three lines are uncommented, or does the error still occur with the above code as it is? I can see why the commented lines would throw an error.

Comment: Are you sure that mcSlideHolder and lastSlide are instanced yet?

Comment: @Corey: uncommented and commented there is no version without error :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either 'dig in' to the nested objects to get to the button instance or you can add event listeners to the button instance before adding it to its parent container then let its click event bubble up.

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what is nested inside of what in your case but I see you're trying getChildByName. getChildByName only gets a direct child (not a child of a child) by its instance name, (not it's variable name).

Dig in example:
lastSlide.getChildByName("endLogoButton").addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, linkClick);

or

lastSlide.name = "myLastSlide";
mcSlideHolder.getChildByName("myLastSlide").getChildByName("endLogoButton").addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, linkClick);

If lastSlide were placed on the stage visually in the Flash IDE, then you could set the instance name myLastSlide there in the properties panel rather than by setting the name property in as3.

Comment: However why can't i do: 
lastSlide.endLogoButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, linkClick);
???

Comment: You can't do that because lastSlide is of type MovieClip which doesn't have a known property called, 'endLogoButton'. Only YOU know that there's an object called that inside. You could however create your own class called MySlide that extends MovieClip and give it a public property called endLogoButton – then you could do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

or maybe: try casting the "lastSlide" to a MovieClip like:

```
MovieClip(mcSlideHolder.getChildByName("lastSlide")).getChildByName("endLogoButton").addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, linkClick);
```

This worked for me several times when the "possible unreferenced object" error popped up when referencing a movieclip that was clearly added to the stage